# Select View and Union and deadlocked in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

Two SQL statements involving common base tables are combined using a UNION.

This query is generated by business objects and the reports worked for sometime.

Recently, we started seeing the following error when the report is run against Production Datamart

> Msg 1205, Level 13, State 2, Line 1
>   Transaction (Process ID 121) was deadlocked on thread | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

I copied the query and ran it in development which has approx same numbers of rows in PROD and it is working there but when ran in production it gives me the same error as above.

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[TESTDetails_CASSETS]
AS      
    SELECT      
        allocation.SeatNumber,LDMCateg.LookupDescription as SeatCategory, 
        Country.CountryName AS Country,
        CityMaster.Cityname AS City, 
        FacilityMaster.FacilityDescription AS Facility, 
        BuildingMaster.BuildingDescription AS Building, 
        FloorMaster.FloorDescription AS Floor, 
        WingMaster.WingDescription AS Wing, 
        BayMaster.BayDescription AS Bay, 
        allocation.AssociateID, allocation.AssociateName, 
        allocation.PoolID AS ProjectID, 
        allocation.PoolName AS ProjectName, 
        allocation.SeatAllocationStartDate, 
        allocation.SeatAllocationEndDate, 
        allocation.ShiftStartTime, 
        allocation.ShiftEndTime, 
        AllocAccount.PoolID as AccountID,
        AllocAccount.PoolName as AccountName, 
        AllocPRactice.PoolID AS PracticeID,
        data.SeatRequestTypeDesc AS SeatAllocationType, 
        dbo.FloorMaster.HCMLocationCode, 
        LDMNetwork.LookupDescription as Network,
        LDMSEZ.LookupDescription as FacilityType,
        LDMSECLUDED.LookupDescription as IsSeatSecluded

    FROM        
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AS allocation 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AllocPRactice on allocation.SeatNumber = AllocPRactice.SeatNumber 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AllocAccount on allocation.SeatNumber = AllocAccount.SeatNumber 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatRequestType(NOLOCK) AS data ON allocation.SeatAllocationTypeID = data.SeatRequestTypeID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatMaster(NOLOCK) AS SeatMr ON SeatMr.SeatNumber = allocation.SeatNumber 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Country(NOLOCK) ON dbo.Country.CountryID = SeatMr.CountryID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.CityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.CityMaster.CityID = SeatMr.CityID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FacilityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityID = SeatMr.FacilityID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BuildingMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingID = SeatMr.BuildingID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FloorMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FloorMaster.FloorID = SeatMr.FloorID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.WingMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.WingId = dbo.WingMaster.WingID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BayMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.BayID = dbo.BayMaster.BayID  
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMCateg on SeatMr.SeatCategoryID = LDMCateg.LookupTypeID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMNetwork on SeatMr.NetworkType = LDMNetwork.LookupTypeID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSEZ on FacilityMaster.FacilityType = LDMSEZ.LookupTypeID 
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSECLUDED on SeatMr.IsSecluded = LDMSECLUDED.LookupTypeID
    WHERE
        (allocation.AssociateID IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (allocation.SeatNumber <> '') 
        --AND (dbo.CityMaster.CityID IN (10, 4, 1))
        AND AllocPRactice.PoolType = 96
        --AND AllocAccount.PoolType = 97
        AND AllocAccount.PoolType = 99
        AND allocation.SeatAllocationTypeID = 1         
        AND LDMCateg.LookupCategoryMasterID = 13
        AND LDMNetwork.LookupCategoryMasterID = 8
        AND LDMSEZ.LookupCategoryMasterID = 12
        AND LDMSECLUDED.LookupCategoryMasterID = 6

UNION

    SELECT     
        allocation.SeatNumber,
        LDMCateg.LookupDescription as SeatCategory, 
        Country.CountryName AS Country, 
        CityMaster.Cityname AS City, 
        FacilityMaster.FacilityDescription AS Facility, 
        BuildingMaster.BuildingDescription AS Building, 
        FloorMaster.FloorDescription AS Floor, 
        WingMaster.WingDescription AS Wing, 
        BayMaster.BayDescription AS Bay, 
        allocation.AssociateID, 
        allocation.AssociateName, 
        allocation.PoolID AS ProjectID, 
        allocation.PoolName AS ProjectName, 
        allocation.SeatAllocationStartDate, 
        allocation.SeatAllocationEndDate, 
        allocation.ShiftStartTime, 
        allocation.ShiftEndTime, 
        SeatMr.AccountID as AccountID,
        SeatMr.AccountName as AccountName,
        SeatMr.BusinessUnitID AS PracticeID,
        data.SeatRequestTypeDesc AS SeatAllocationType, 
        dbo.FloorMaster.HCMLocationCode, 
        LDMNetwork.LookupDescription as Network,
        LDMSEZ.LookupDescription as FacilityType,
        LDMSECLUDED.LookupDescription as IsSeatSecluded                  
    FROM    
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AS allocation INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatRequestType(NOLOCK) AS data ON allocation.SeatAllocationTypeID = data.SeatRequestTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatMaster(NOLOCK) AS SeatMr ON SeatMr.SeatNumber = allocation.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.Country(NOLOCK) ON dbo.Country.CountryID = SeatMr.CountryID INNER JOIN
        dbo.CityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.CityMaster.CityID = SeatMr.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FacilityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityID = SeatMr.FacilityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BuildingMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingID = SeatMr.BuildingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FloorMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FloorMaster.FloorID = SeatMr.FloorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.WingMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.WingId = dbo.WingMaster.WingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BayMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.BayID = dbo.BayMaster.BayID  INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMCateg on SeatMr.SeatCategoryID = LDMCateg.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMNetwork on SeatMr.NetworkType = LDMNetwork.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSEZ on FacilityMaster.FacilityType = LDMSEZ.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSECLUDED on SeatMr.IsSecluded = LDMSECLUDED.LookupTypeID 
    WHERE     
        (allocation.AssociateID IS NOT NULL) 
        AND (allocation.SeatNumber <> '') 
        --AND (dbo.CityMaster.CityID IN (10, 4, 1))
        AND allocation.SeatAllocationTypeID = 2
        AND LDMCateg.LookupCategoryMasterID = 13
        AND LDMNetwork.LookupCategoryMasterID = 8
        AND LDMSEZ.LookupCategoryMasterID = 12
        AND LDMSECLUDED.LookupCategoryMasterID = 6

UNION

    SELECT      
        SeatMr.SeatNumber,
        LDMCateg.LookupDescription as SeatCategory, 
        Country.CountryName AS Country, 
        CityMaster.Cityname AS City, 
        FacilityMaster.FacilityDescription AS Facility, 
        BuildingMaster.BuildingDescription AS Building, 
        FloorMaster.FloorDescription AS Floor, 
        WingMaster.WingDescription AS Wing, 
        BayMaster.BayDescription AS Bay, 
        NULL AS AssociateID, 
        NULL AS AssociateName, 
        NULL AS ProjectID, 
        NULL AS ProjectName, 
        NULL AS SeatAllocationStartDate, 
        NULL AS SeatAllocationEndDate, 
        NULL AS ShiftStartTime, 
        NULL AS ShiftEndTime, 
        NULL AS AccountID, 
        NULL AS AccountName, 
        NULL AS PracticeID,
        NULL AS SeatAllocationType, 
        FloorMaster.HCMLocationCode, 
        LDMNetwork.LookupDescription as Network,
        LDMSEZ.LookupDescription as FacilityType,
        LDMSECLUDED.LookupDescription as IsSeatSecluded
    FROM              
        dbo.SeatMaster(NOLOCK) AS SeatMr INNER JOIN
        dbo.Country(NOLOCK) ON dbo.Country.CountryID = SeatMr.CountryID INNER JOIN
        dbo.CityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.CityMaster.CityID = SeatMr.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FacilityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityID = SeatMr.FacilityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BuildingMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingID = SeatMr.BuildingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FloorMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FloorMaster.FloorID = SeatMr.FloorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.WingMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.WingId = dbo.WingMaster.WingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BayMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.BayID = dbo.BayMaster.BayID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMCateg on SeatMr.SeatCategoryID = LDMCateg.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMNetwork on SeatMr.NetworkType = LDMNetwork.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSEZ on FacilityMaster.FacilityType = LDMSEZ.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSECLUDED on SeatMr.IsSecluded = LDMSECLUDED.LookupTypeID
    WHERE     
        (SeatMr.SeatNumber <> '') 
        --AND (dbo.CityMaster.CityID IN (10, 4, 1))
        AND SeatMr.BusinessUnitID is NULL and SeatMr.AccountID is NULL
        AND SeatMr.SeatNumber NOT IN (SELECT SeatNumber FROM SeatAllocation WHERE SeatAllocationTypeID = 2)
        AND LDMCateg.LookupCategoryMasterID = 13
        AND LDMNetwork.LookupCategoryMasterID = 8
        AND LDMSEZ.LookupCategoryMasterID = 12
        AND LDMSECLUDED.LookupCategoryMasterID = 6

UNION

    SELECT      
        SeatMr.SeatNumber,
        LDMCateg.LookupDescription as SeatCategory, 
        Country.CountryName AS Country, 
        CityMaster.Cityname AS City, 
        FacilityMaster.FacilityDescription AS Facility, 
        BuildingMaster.BuildingDescription AS Building, 
        FloorMaster.FloorDescription AS Floor, 
        WingMaster.WingDescription AS Wing, 
        BayMaster.BayDescription AS Bay, 
        NULL AS AssociateID, 
        NULL AS AssociateName, 
        NULL AS ProjectID, 
        NULL AS ProjectName, 
        NULL AS SeatAllocationStartDate, 
        NULL AS SeatAllocationEndDate, 
        NULL AS ShiftStartTime, 
        NULL AS ShiftEndTime, 
        NULL AS AccountID, 
        NULL AS AccountName, 
        Allocation.PoolID AS PracticeID,
        NULL AS SeatAllocationType, 
        FloorMaster.HCMLocationCode, 
        LDMNetwork.LookupDescription as Network,
        LDMSEZ.LookupDescription as FacilityType,
        LDMSECLUDED.LookupDescription as IsSeatSecluded
    FROM              
        dbo.SeatMaster(NOLOCK) AS SeatMr INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) as Allocation on SeatMr.SeatNumber = Allocation.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.Country(NOLOCK) ON dbo.Country.CountryID = SeatMr.CountryID INNER JOIN
        dbo.CityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.CityMaster.CityID = SeatMr.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FacilityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityID = SeatMr.FacilityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BuildingMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingID = SeatMr.BuildingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FloorMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FloorMaster.FloorID = SeatMr.FloorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.WingMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.WingId = dbo.WingMaster.WingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BayMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.BayID = dbo.BayMaster.BayID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMCateg on SeatMr.SeatCategoryID = LDMCateg.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMNetwork on SeatMr.NetworkType = LDMNetwork.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSEZ on FacilityMaster.FacilityType = LDMSEZ.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSECLUDED on SeatMr.IsSecluded = LDMSECLUDED.LookupTypeID
    WHERE     
        (SeatMr.SeatNumber <> '') 
        --AND (dbo.CityMaster.CityID IN (10, 4, 1)) 
        AND SeatMr.BusinessUnitID is Not NULL 
        and SeatMr.AccountID is NULL
        and Allocation.PoolType = 96
        AND LDMCateg.LookupCategoryMasterID = 13
        AND LDMNetwork.LookupCategoryMasterID = 8
        AND LDMSEZ.LookupCategoryMasterID = 12
        AND LDMSECLUDED.LookupCategoryMasterID = 6


UNION

    SELECT     
        SeatMr.SeatNumber,
        LDMCateg.LookupDescription as SeatCategory, 
        dbo.Country.CountryName AS Country, 
        dbo.CityMaster.Cityname AS City, 
        dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityDescription AS Facility, 
        dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingDescription AS Building, 
        dbo.FloorMaster.FloorDescription AS Floor, 
        dbo.WingMaster.WingDescription AS Wing, 
        dbo.BayMaster.BayDescription AS Bay, 
        NULL AS AssociateID, 
        NULL AS AssociateName, 
        NULL AS ProjectID, 
        NULL AS ProjectName, 
        NULL AS SeatAllocationStartDate, 
        NULL AS SeatAllocationEndDate, 
        NULL AS ShiftStartTime, 
        NULL AS ShiftEndTime, 
        Allocation.PoolID AS AccountID, 
        Allocation.PoolName AS AccountName, 
        AllocPractice.PoolID AS PracticeID,
        NULL AS SeatAllocationType, 
        FloorMaster.HCMLocationCode,
        LDMNetwork.LookupDescription as Network,
        LDMSEZ.LookupDescription as FacilityType,
        LDMSECLUDED.LookupDescription as IsSeatSecluded
    FROM              
        dbo.SeatMaster(NOLOCK) AS SeatMr INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) as Allocation on SeatMr.SeatNumber = Allocation.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation AllocPractice on allocation.SeatNumber = AllocPRactice.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.Country(NOLOCK) ON dbo.Country.CountryID = SeatMr.CountryID INNER JOIN
        dbo.CityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.CityMaster.CityID = SeatMr.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FacilityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityID = SeatMr.FacilityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BuildingMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingID = SeatMr.BuildingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FloorMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FloorMaster.FloorID = SeatMr.FloorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.WingMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.WingId = dbo.WingMaster.WingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BayMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.BayID = dbo.BayMaster.BayID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMCateg on SeatMr.SeatCategoryID = LDMCateg.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMNetwork on SeatMr.NetworkType = LDMNetwork.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSEZ on FacilityMaster.FacilityType = LDMSEZ.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSECLUDED on SeatMr.IsSecluded = LDMSECLUDED.LookupTypeID
    WHERE     
        (SeatMr.SeatNumber <> '') 
        --AND (dbo.CityMaster.CityID IN (10, 4, 1)) 
        AND SeatMr.BusinessUnitID IS NOT NULL 
        and SeatMr.AccountID IS NOT NULL
        --and Allocation.PoolType = 97 
        and Allocation.PoolType = 99
        AND AllocPractice.PoolType = 96
        AND SeatMr.SeatNumber NOT IN
        (
            SELECT
                alloc.SeatNumber
            FROM        
                dbo.SeatAllocation AS alloc INNER JOIN
                dbo.SeatRequestType AS data ON alloc.SeatAllocationTypeID = data.SeatRequestTypeID INNER JOIN
                dbo.SeatMaster AS SeatMr ON SeatMr.SeatNumber = alloc.SeatNumber 
            WHERE     
                alloc.PoolType = 98
        )
        AND LDMCateg.LookupCategoryMasterID = 13
        AND LDMNetwork.LookupCategoryMasterID = 8
        AND LDMSEZ.LookupCategoryMasterID = 12
        AND LDMSECLUDED.LookupCategoryMasterID = 6

UNION

    SELECT      
        ProjectAllocation.SeatNumber,
        LDMCateg.LookupDescription as SeatCategory, 
        Country.CountryName AS Country, 
        CityMaster.Cityname AS City,
        FacilityMaster.FacilityDescription AS Facility, 
        BuildingMaster.BuildingDescription AS Building, 
        FloorMaster.FloorDescription AS Floor, 
        WingMaster.WingDescription AS Wing, 
        BayMaster.BayDescription AS Bay, 
        ProjectAllocation.AssociateID, 
        ProjectAllocation.AssociateName, 
        ProjectAllocation.PoolID AS ProjectID, 
        ProjectAllocation.PoolName AS ProjectName, 
        ProjectAllocation.SeatAllocationStartDate, 
        ProjectAllocation.SeatAllocationEndDate, 
        ProjectAllocation.ShiftStartTime, 
        ProjectAllocation.ShiftEndTime,
        AccountAllocation.PoolID AccountID, 
        AccountAllocation.PoolName AccountName, 
        PracticeAllocation.PoolID PracticeID, 
        data.SeatRequestTypeDesc AS SeatAllocationType, 
        FloorMaster.HCMLocationCode,
        LDMNetwork.LookupDescription as Network,
        LDMSEZ.LookupDescription as FacilityType,
        LDMSECLUDED.LookupDescription as IsSeatSecluded

    FROM
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AS ProjectAllocation INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatMaster(NOLOCK) AS SeatMr ON SeatMr.SeatNumber = ProjectAllocation.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AS AccountAllocation ON AccountAllocation.SeatNumber = SeatMr.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatAllocation(NOLOCK) AS PracticeAllocation ON PracticeAllocation.SeatNumber = SeatMr.SeatNumber INNER JOIN
        dbo.SeatRequestType(NOLOCK) AS data ON ProjectAllocation.SeatAllocationTypeID = data.SeatRequestTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.Country(NOLOCK) ON dbo.Country.CountryID = SeatMr.CountryID INNER JOIN
        dbo.CityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.CityMaster.CityID = SeatMr.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FacilityMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FacilityMaster.FacilityID = SeatMr.FacilityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BuildingMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.BuildingMaster.BuildingID = SeatMr.BuildingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.FloorMaster(NOLOCK) ON dbo.FloorMaster.FloorID = SeatMr.FloorID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.WingMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.WingId = dbo.WingMaster.WingID LEFT OUTER JOIN
        dbo.BayMaster(NOLOCK) ON SeatMr.BayID = dbo.BayMaster.BayID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMCateg on SeatMr.SeatCategoryID = LDMCateg.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMNetwork on SeatMr.NetworkType = LDMNetwork.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSEZ on FacilityMaster.FacilityType = LDMSEZ.LookupTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.LookupDataMaster(NOLOCK) LDMSECLUDED on SeatMr.IsSecluded = LDMSECLUDED.LookupTypeID

    WHERE     
        (ProjectAllocation.AssociateID  is NULL) 
        AND (ProjectAllocation.SeatNumber <> '') 
        AND SeatMr.BusinessUnitID IS NOT NULL 
        AND SeatMr.AccountID IS NOT NULL 
        AND ProjectAllocation.PoolType = 98
        --AND AccountAllocation.PoolType = 97 
        AND AccountAllocation.PoolType = 99
        AND PracticeAllocation.PoolType = 96
        AND LDMCateg.LookupCategoryMasterID = 13
        AND LDMNetwork.LookupCategoryMasterID = 8
        AND LDMSEZ.LookupCategoryMasterID = 12
        AND LDMSECLUDED.LookupCategoryMasterID = 6
GO
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: add the query hint: with (nolock) on data you dont think will get updated while the query runs??

Comment: Do you have indexes? Maybe your queries are doing table scans which lock the entire table.

Comment: @drewlander i have added NOLOCK the issues still remains somehow dono why!!

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič Yes, indexes are also there for the tables.

Comment: Maybe include queries to your question.
BTW: try to avoid UNION, go with UNION ALL (if possible, of course), you'll gain performance.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič add the view queries .. its a long one..

Comment: Have you checked the explain plan for each query? Especially the section around LookupDataMaster seems suspicious to me.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič the problem is we dont have access to prod server to examine that...

Comment: This complicates the issue quite a lot. Since you said " the reports worked for sometime" my bet is on indexes - bigger number of rows broke you explain plan. There's (at least) one index missing. Start with table LookupDataMaster and work from there.

Comment: Can we see the query execution plan? Im curious of table scans....

Comment: @drewlander we dont have access to that in prod environment.. so have to resolve without it..

Comment: With all due respect, the same execution plan should exist if you execute this in your test environment.  And if you prod env has different schema than test there is a fundamental issue with deployment in your project.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your typical deadlock, and typical deadlock debugging techniques won't work here.  You're deadlocking on "thread | communication buffer resources", not data pages.  Also, this makes for an extremely difficult case for anyone else to reproduce and debug on our local computers.

Since it appears your SELECT and FROM clauses are nearly identical, you may be able to rewrite this by simply having four ORs in your WHERE clause.  It would require doing left joins to

WHERE (a IS NOT NULL AND b = 1) OR (a IS NOT NULL AND b = 2) OR (a IS NULL AND b = 0)

Just as a warning, my method would have the same effect as changing your UNIONs to UNION ALLs, meaning that you won't get duplicate rows if something meets two of the sets of criteria.  That may be a good thing, it may be a bad thing, but it is definitely something you should be aware of.

If that doesn't work for you, just keep simplifying it until you get rid of the deadlock.  Possibly getting into looking at the execution plan to find index changes that could be made to make this more efficient, leaving the query using less resources to deadlock on.  Maybe even going so far as to make this a table-valued function where you could run each one separately and put the results in a temp table, then return the resulting temp table.

With it being an odd case, you're not going to find much documentation on it, and speculated answers like mine may be the best you'll be able to do without opening a case with Microsoft.